How to Connect all Sockets of a Node Group to the Group Input Node in one click
I built a node tree for my personal project that ended up pretty large. I then had to connect all of the node sockets to the group input node in order to use group parameters directly from the modifier tab.
It was a very tedious and dumb process. So I wonder if there is any way that I can automate this task in the future, namely plugging all sockets of a Node Group to the Group input Node.
Pic 1: Simple Example
Pic 2: Complex Example
P.S: I don't know python or any programming language for that matter.   


1. Paste to Text Editor and hit the run button


import bpy

ALL_INPUT_SOCKET_TYPES = { # Blender version 4.2
    'NodeSocketString',
    'NodeSocketBool',
    'NodeSocketMaterial',
    'NodeSocketVector',
    'NodeSocketInt',
    'NodeSocketMenu',
    'NodeSocketCollection',
    'NodeSocketGeometry',
    'NodeSocketTexture',
    'NodeSocketFloat',
    'NodeSocketColor',
    'NodeSocketObject',
    'NodeSocketRotation',
    'NodeSocketMatrix',
    'NodeSocketImage'}

def node_socket_subtype_split(bl_idname):
    # 'NodeSocketVectorTranslation' --> 'NodeSocketVector', 'Translation'
    for r in range(12, len(bl_idname)):
        if bl_idname[ : r] in ALL_INPUT_SOCKET_TYPES:
            return bl_idname[ : r], bl_idname[r : ]
    return bl_idname, ''

def find_group_input(node_group):
    for node in node_group.nodes:
        if node.bl_idname == "NodeGroupInput":
            return node

    return None

class GeometryNodesGroupSocketToInput(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "node.geometry_nodes_group_socket_to_input"
    bl_label = "Geometry Nodes Group Socket to Input"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def warning(self, info=""):
        self.report({'WARNING'}, info)
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    def execute(self, context):
        context.active_node

        if not hasattr(context, 'active_node') or not context.active_node:
            return self.warning('Active node not found')

        node_group = None
        for space in context.area.spaces:
            if space.type == "NODE_EDITOR":
                node_group = space.edit_tree
                break

        if not node_group:
            return self.warning('Node Tree not found')

        active_group = node_group.nodes.active
        if not active_group:
            return self.warning('Active Group not found, select a Group first')

        group_input = find_group_input(node_group)
        if not group_input:
            group_input = node_group.nodes.new(type="NodeGroupInput")

        new_socket = node_group.interface.new_socket
        new_link = node_group.links.new

        for inp in active_group.inputs:
            socket_type, subtype = node_socket_subtype_split(inp.bl_idname)
            if socket_type in ALL_INPUT_SOCKET_TYPES:
                socket = new_socket(inp.name, description='', in_out='INPUT', socket_type=socket_type, parent=None)

                if subtype:
                    try:
                        socket.subtype = subtype.upper()
                    except:
                        pass

                new_link(inp, group_input.outputs[socket.identifier])


        return {'FINISHED'}

class NodeUtilsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "NODE_UTILS_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Utils Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Utils"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return context.area.ui_type == "GeometryNodeTree"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator('node.geometry_nodes_group_socket_to_input', text='Connect to Input')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GeometryNodesGroupSocketToInput)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeUtilsPanel)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GeometryNodesGroupSocketToInput)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeUtilsPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

2. Make a node group active in Geometry Node Editor

3. Hit the Connect button
N-Panel > Utils > Connect to Input

All input socket will connect to Group Input Bottom


Convert to Addon
1. Save Text as __init__.py to a folder

2. Make .toml file
Save Text as blender_manifest.toml to the folder
schema_version = "1.0.0"

id = "My_Addon"
version = "1.1.1"
name = "My Addon"
tagline = "Do myself"
maintainer = "Me"
type = "add-on"

website = "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/327277/how-to-connect-all-sockets-of-a-node-group-to-the-group-input-node-in-one-click/327295#327295"

tags = ["User Interface"]

blender_version_min = "4.2.0"

license = [
  "SPDX:GPL-3.0-or-later",
]


3. Zip the folder and install from disk

4. Select the zip folder and save preference
